# Black lines between absolute positioned images

Tags: html, css

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wtw7ebkr/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="navsocial">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gIVEWHc.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sUEWyjj.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GT4Unbz.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navsocial {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 5px;
}

#navsocial img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Under chrome and firefox, it displays 2 black lines between facebook and twitter, and twitter and gplus icons.

1. Why are those lines there?
2. How can I get rid of them?

Screenshot of what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVO1U.png

Comment: Hacker, if this answers your question, please accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines are there because hyperlink anchors, denoted in HTML by `a`, have an underline by default

You need to apply `text-decoration: none;` to the `a` anchor

```
#navsocial a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL3a6ras/)